# Can any moral command be cogently expressed in the negative?

Tags: ethics, metaphysics

I've been thinking about how people devise ethical systems, and if in fact we could create an ethical system that allows for positive command. I think I, and probably most people I meet, am at my core a utilitarian as it feels the most intuitively isomorphic way of expressing ethical inclination. However, there keep being wrenches thrown in to that general worldview, and I'm wondering whether a perfect system could allow for positive command.

For example, the difficult case of the [Kitty Genovese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Kitty_Genovese) wherein I'm genuinely agnostic whether people could be held accountable for *not* acting. Similarly, Philippa Foot's famous (and by this point infamous)  raises serious concerns about this fundamentally utilitarian ideal - and its similar cases lead me to reconsider the principle entirely.

So, would I want to accept a society that imposed a command of "Thou shalt give x amount of charity every day" (or something along those lines).

My gut reaction is no. It feels too intrusive and restrictive. And, if we just extrapolate upwards, it then becomes easy to reject all notions of positive command, and to want to build a system with only negative commands (i.e. "Thou shalt not kill").

However, this is only a possible consideration if there exist moral commands which can *not* be cogently expressed by their negation. For the example above, I'm trying to figure out a way to express the idea of "Thou shalt give x amount of charity every day" as a negative command, but I can't think of an example. The only things that come to mind are "Thou shalt not pass by a struggling neighbor or a struggling friend or a struggling [fill in the blank]..." ad infinitum. To express this idea in a negative, one would need to express every possible scenario which one cannot allow for, and using the principle of [plenitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_plenitude), this is uncountably many and therefore impossible. So, to my mind, the idea of "Thou shalt give charity" feels inexpressible in its negation in a finite sense, and therefore should not be included in our moral system.

My question is am I wrong? Is it actually possible to express any theorem or command **finitely** (or, cogently) by its negation? Or, would this maybe be a good boundary for an ethical system?

Comment: You might not dislike this article: http://www.academia.edu/1978779/Searles_Ontology_of_Human_Rights

Comment: The Genovese case did not happen as you say it did. *More recent investigations have questioned the original version of events. A 2007 study found many of the purported facts about the murder to be unfounded, stating there was "no evidence for the presence of 38 witnesses, or that witnesses observed the murder, or that witnesses remained inactive* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murder_of_Kitty_Genovese#Reaction Do your homework, don't rely on urban legends.

Answer (score 2):

I am not OK with utilitarianism for other reasons, it encourages too much intelligence (therefore elitism and lawyering) and too little empathy (because 'missing' someone else's perspective 'accidentally' is rewarded by getting your own way.)  So I will answer from a different context.

Given the assumptions about Categories, in Kant, maxims can always be positive.  I would argue that they should always be so.

Negation has problems of its own.  We could follow down the Cretan paradox, etc.  But enough thought has been invested here for us to realize that negation is a very unstable operation in general.  Real things have real opposites, instead of vague lacunae.  Whereas negative statements can be absolute nonsense.  There is no call to depend upon the less certain form.

But more relevantly, it is obvious that moral distinctions are not generally clear.  Negation introduces to morality a notion of dichotomy that is basically alien to it in most forms.  Maxims like "Don't lie." are not always meaningful.  It is often difficult to know when you are lying, and, to my mind, that means the rule itself needs improving.

The problem you ascribe to negation is actually not about negation, and it is a supporting motive to avoid negation.  The question is what is expected, permitted or compelled and to what degree.  And there are places in morality that call for each.  "Do not kill" only *seems* to clarify whether this should be expected, permitted or compelled.  Am I obligated, permitted or expected to stop someone from killing to save other lives?  So how does the negative form do anything but hide the real need for clarification?

Considering that, positive maxims generally have more content and less ambiguity.  "Allow any other the freedom to live" works better than "Don't kill" because it is about the *freedom* to live, and gives more handhold to the reasons for euthanasia, suicide, etc. It naturally raises the questions 'is insanity freedom?', 'can one choose to relinquish choice?'  The closed form given by negation loses the motivation.

Likewise for lying "Don't lie" is nice, and as far as it goes I respect Kant's reasoning relative to it.  But the maxim can be improved by the work needed to put it into a positive form.  This requires considering motivations for lying and can disambiguate 'lies' like promises and mythology.  "When you speak, convey what you believe." means a great deal more, and is less ambiguous at the point of application.

Comment: What does "encourages too much intelligence (therefore elitism and lawyering)" mean? If intelligence is something Util. promotes, it's because intelligence is generally a good, right?

Comment: Also, Kant's example of a maxim about lying (in the Groundwork, and more fully realized in the Second Critique) is of course not "don't lie" but something closer to what you describe as the less ambiguous version. It includes circumstances and goals.

Comment: @ChristopherE Intelligence is great for a lot of things, but if you want a moral system to work, your regular Joe has to be able to play along with the rest of us, or he will become dependent upon authorities and get manipulated.  So requiring too much intelligence or too much capacity for detail to understand moral arguments is a flaw in any ethical system, and utilitarianism has that flaw in spades.

Comment: @ChristopherE He elaborates conditions of application, but the overall duty is not to lie.  It retains its negative character.  I think it needs to do so in order to accommodate our inability to really understand the truth.  I am less attached to the objectivity of truth, and would trade it for a more positive, directive maxim.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Since I've never heard that objection to Utilitarianism, and it seems to me counterintuitive, do you have a citation for who has developed it?

Comment: @ChristopherE Kant points it up in his discussion of maturity, sentiment and other aspects of applying morality in "What is Enlightenment".  It seems unkind (and thus unlikely) that God would make something unfairly distributed necessary for something mandatory.  He is not in the business of criticizing the competition, but it just happens to a problem with most varieties of Utilitarianism in my own opinion.

Comment: @ChristopherE  Come to think of it I am also skewing Kant's opinion on this in other ways.  It is a more modern notion that manipulation is the price of dependency.  For Kant, given the emphasis on autonomy, depending upon guidance for morality was just plain bad in its own right.  Failing to grow out of it was avoidable immaturity, which was basically the sin of sloth.

Comment: Okay but has anyone ever published this sort of criticism as applying specifically to any actual version of utilitarianism?

Comment: @ChristopherE: Well, Sidgwick notes "And thus a Utilitarian may reasonably desire, on Utilitarian principles, that some of his conclusions should be rejected by mankind generally; or even that the vulgar should keep aloof from his system as a whole, in so far as the inevitable indefiniteness and complexity of its calculations render it likely to lead to bad results in their hands."  So even prominent pro-Utilitarian thinkers do not trust ordinary people to be Utilitarians.  He does not find this a weakness, but it is the core of many attacks that imply Utilitarianism is classist.

Comment: @ChristopherE  So this makes the average man dependent upon outside instruction, or manipulation, for his ethics.  But Sidgwick does not see that as a bad thing.  From Kant's perspective it is, because that person is being limited externally, and loses autonomy.  And from a 'Critical Theory' perspective, we know that manipulation is very hard to do psychologically without it becoming systematically unfair, even under the best of motives.

Comment: @ChristopherE  Both of those can be rendered into Utilitarian terms themselves.  So from that POV, Classical Utilitarianism is internally inconsistent if it values freedom or takes real human psychology into account.  I am not aware of anyone who has put these together, but I really can't imagine its not happening.  (Sorry for the length in comments -- maybe you should make this a question?)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with "express". You can easily write "Thou shalt not not-give to charity every day" or even replace "not-give" with a synonym like "shun", from mathematical/logical point of view there is no difference between positives and negatives. What you need is a more robust notion of "positive action" to distinguish between command and prohibition, e.g. a system where rejection is not expressed by logical negation, and "negative facts" are established independently. Bremer discusses such frameworks in [Assertion and Rejection](http://www.mbph.de/Logic/Para/AssertionAndRejection.pdf):

> "*Rejection concerns the conviction that some fact is absent. Assertion of the opposite in distinction claims some fact to be present, namely a negative fact.*"

Religious ethics, Christian or Islamic, employs both God's commands and prohibitions, so presumably they do envision commands that can not be cogently expressed by their negations, see [Divine Command Theory](http://www.iep.utm.edu/divine-c). Note that once we have means of establishing negatives directly, just as positives, the issue shifts to the more practical problem of making judgement calls on various kinds of facts.

Going back to the charity example, "Thou shalt not shun charity" has perhaps enough flexibility to preclude the gut reaction against intrusiveness and restrictiveness, and at the same time "shun" can be constructively interpreted as a practically establishable "negative fact". Of course, not by strict logic modeled on scientific observations and experiments, but ethics is not science. Outside of classical logic it may not be necessary to "express every possible scenario". Establishing whether someone shunned charity or not will require judgement calls based on some, perhaps vague, communal norms. They may or may not involve frequency and amounts in a context dependent way, with the context including giver's means, price levels, inflation rate, etc. But presumably it can be reasonably accomplished in most cases, and hence can be ethically functional. Similarly, "Thou shalt love thy neighbor" can be made contextually meaningful. The problem of indefinite scope only arises when one tries to come up with absolutist descriptions valid for all times and places, which is typically unworkable.